# How to extract link from button in message with telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I want to extract the inline button link from the text in a telegram channel, How can I do it?
thanks

I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is a link (and doesn't use callbacks or other types of buttons), you can use the [`Button.url`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/quick-references/objects-reference.html#button) property:

```py
# row and col are 0-based indices of the row and column where the button is
# message is the Message with buttons
print(message.buttons[row][col].url)
```